# How to block anonymous users from using my website widgets?

Tags: php, widget, drupal-6

I have an wookie widget and i need to integrate the widget only in the websites i prefer..
Anonymous users should not be able to access the widgets. Only authenticated users of my website should be able to use the widgets.

(My widget is designed inside an iframe. So it is possible for anonymous users to access the widget by copying the iframe src.)

Please help me how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Drupal has a pretty nice permission system (aka roles). You can modify visibility of content and blocks according to their role.

Comment: My widget is designed inside an iframe. So it is possible for anonymous users to access the widget by copying the iframe src. Please help me in this scenario

Comment: You could put the iframe inside of a block and change the permissions to the block. Otherwise you'll have to use Drupal's PHP filter and use vimalnath's solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could user the [user_is_logged_in](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_is_logged_in/6) function inside any of your tpl file to check if the user is logged in(authenticated user) or anonymous user:

```
<?php if (user_is_logged_in()): ?>

  <p>Hello, am authenticated </p>

<?php else:?>

  <p>Hello, am anonymous </p>

<?php endif;?
```

You could also use the [$logged_in](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/6) variable instead to accomplish this:

**$logged_in**: returns TRUE if the user is registered and signed in.

```
 <?php if ($logged_in): ?>

          <p>Hello, am authenticated </p>

        <?php else:?>

          <p>Hello, am anonymous </p>

        <?php endif;?
```